# R! posIXCT in sqldf

Tags: r, posixct, sqldf

first time question, so if I missed something I apologize:

I imported an excel file into R! using XLconnect, the str() function is as follow:

```
data.frame':    931 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Media        : chr  "EEM" "EEM" "EEM" "EEM" ...
 $ Month        : POSIXct, format: "2014-08-01" "2014-08-01" "2014-08-01" "2014-08-01" ...
 $ Request_Row  : num  8 25 26 37 38 44 53 62 69 83 ...
 $ Total_Click  : num  12 9 9 8 8 8 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ Match_Type   : chr  "S" "S" "S" "S" ...
```

when I use the following sqldf I get no rows selected, anyway to what could be wrong:

```
sqldf(" select Media, sum(Total_Click) , avg(Request_Row), min(Request_Row) , max(Request_Row), count(distinct(Media)) from All_Data 
      where Request_Row < 100  
      and month='2014-09-01'
      group by 1,2 order by 2,6 desc ")

<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Thanks for the help

Vj

Comment: does the month '2014-09-01' actually exist in the excel file?

Comment: And do note that `month != Month`. (R is case sensitive and you might think about fixing your question title since it's "just ugly" at the moment.)

Comment: Hearing no response I will assume that the spelling is the issue and vote to close as a simple typo.

Comment: Thanks Guys! this solved the problem, strftime('%Y-%m-%d', month, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') ='2014-08-01'

Comment: The problem here was not just month/Month. There were multiple problems with the code as outlined in my answer so I am voting to re-open.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what is intended but the code shown has these problems:

1. `Month` is used in the data but `month` is used in the SQL statement
2. SQLite has no date or time types and so if you send a POSIXct value to SQLite it will be interpreted as the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch (in GMT time zone).  Thus the comparison of the month to a character string won't work.  You can convert the number of seconds to yy-mm-dd using the SQLite `strftime` or `date` functions.  Alternately use a database that has datetime types.  sqldf supports the H2 database and it supports date and time types.
3. The statement is trying to group by `Media` and `sum(Total_Click)`.  Grouping by an aggregated value is not legal although perhaps it could be done by nesting selects depending on what you intended.
4. Since the statement is grouping by `Media`  the expressoin `count(distinct(Media)) from`All_Data will always be 1 since there can only be one `Media` in such a group.

You will need to clarify what your intent is but if we drop or fix up the various points we can get this:

```
sqldf("select 
          Media,
          sum(Total_Click) sum_Total_Click, 
          avg(Request_Row) avg_Request_Row, 
          min(Request_Row) min_Request_Row,
          max(Request_Row) max_Request_Row
    from All_Data
    where Request_Row < 100
    and date(month, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') = '2014-08-01'
    group by 1 order by 2 desc")
```

which gives:

```
  Media sum_Total_Click avg_Request_Row min_Request_Row max_Request_Row
1   EEM              38              24               8              37
```

**RH2** To use the RH2 package and H2 database instead be sure you have Java and RH2 installed (RH2 includes the H2 database so that does *not* need to be separately installed) and then:

```
library(RH2)
library(sqldf)
sqldf("...")
```

where the ... is replaced with the same SQL statement except the date comparison simplifies to this line:

```
and month = '2014-08-01'
```

**Data:** When posting to the SO R tag please show your data using `dput`.  In this case this was used:

```
All_Data <-
structure(list(Media = c("EEM", "EEM", "EEM", "EEM"), Month = structure(c(1406865600, 
1406865600, 1406865600, 1406865600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), Request_Row = c(8, 25, 26, 37), Total_Click = c(12, 
9, 9, 8), Match_Type = c("S", "S", "S", "S")), .Names = c("Media", 
"Month", "Request_Row", "Total_Click", "Match_Type"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Update:** Misc revisions.

Comment: I do apologize for delay in response ; The month to Month typo isn't the problem I have tested that, it was a typo here not in the original R code Thanks
VJ